# Print using usb Port in Dos

Tags: command-line, usb, printing, ms-dos

I am trying to (hard) print a file in Dos using a printer that is connected via **`USB Port`**.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: when you say `command line` you mean no OS is installed in your machine other than the DOS? If that is so, then I'm wondering even if your printer would be detected by the system!

Comment: What drivers are you using? Which Dos? FreeDOS actually does have [USB drivers](http://www.freedos.org/software/?prog=usbdos) (including printers, according to the description), but that's not something you find installed out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this directly from MS-DOS:
According to the MS-DOS compatible printers documentation USB printers will NOT work unless the printer can be connected via parallel port too.

DOS does not know USB printing, but a USB port can be redirected in the same way as a network port (NET USE LPT1 \PC-Name\PrinterName).

---

*Although the answer is no I'd give this a deeper testing.
That would require USBASPI.SYS, or a similar universal file to access USB under MS-DOS. Then theres the need for the .sys compatible with the printer (like PRINTER.SYS). 
Then add them in config.sys:
DeviceHigh=USBASPI.SYS /v /w /e
DeviceHigh=PRINTER.SYS
Then I'd probably need the printer equivalent of MSCDEX.EXE which I don't know to exist.*

If you want this from under any version of windows (printing from a DOS app) it is possible and there are many applications that can do that.